# Route SSH to internal virtual network via centos7 vm router

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, routing, port-forwarding

Trying to route ssh traffic to vm servers in isolated network on a centos7 KVM host. Can ping from either side but ssh times out.

I'm connected to my home router from work via vpn.

i have a static route to the external interface on centos7 vm router (functioning correctly with ip forwarding etc).

Internal vm, anohter centos7 server can update from internet and ping lan clients and vice versa

When i try to ssh to the internal vm from work pc it times out. firewalld on both vm router(internal and external interfaces) and internal server has ssh enabled in services

**Setup:**
[home route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZofmW.png)

10.0.1.2 - vpn client
10.0.0.20 - ext if vm router
10.0.10.2 - int if vm router
10.0.10.10 - internal centos7 server

**VPN Config:**
push "route 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "redirect-gateway def1"

i will be adding more servers to this internal network so i don't want to just forward port 22 to 10.0.10.10 i need it forwarded to 10.0.10.* while also still retaining the ability to manage the vm router via ssh on the external ip.

I can ssh to the server (10.0.10.10) from 10.0.0.0 and 10.0.10.0 networks

Hope this makes sense. This is a home test lab.

[iptables output](https://pastebin.com/w7p63HwQ)

Comment: _packets don't lie_: try to sniff the packets with `tcpdump` on the nodes involved (the internal server, the vm router, your pc) and see where they get lost or they are not being forwarded. Another option would be to try to use `traceroute  -T -p 22 10.0.10.10`

Comment: @EnricoPolesel i'm pretty sure its a problem with routing in the vm router, pings works fine.. i just don't know what firewall-cmd cmds i need.

Comment: With `traceroute` you can be sure about that, with `tcpdump` you can check that all addresses and interfaces are correct. Then with `iptables -L` you can check if there are some rule blocking the forwarding.

Comment: @EnricoPolesel no nix traceroute, sorry should have mentioned, work pc is win7, im using putty to ssh.

Comment: what kind of network did you declare to attach your VM's NICs on the host: if NATed , you need to add qemu some port-forwarding (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487538/port-forwarding-on-nat-using-kvm-qemu )

Comment: @tonioc vm router has 2 nics, external bridged (internet), internal virtual network (no dhcp, no static route defined in qemu), both nics use virtio

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone that may be building a similar setup to this, here is the firewalld line that i needed. eth1 is the external interface on the centos ROUTER vm

`firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -I FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT`